# C# sorting a List of Strings by a List of Doubles

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create a list of strings that represent the top five of the summed values.

I have a database with hundreds of bills pertaining to different services

ex. electric $600 January 2013
Water $50 January 2013

I need to sum all the same services 
which I have done here

```
public List<Double> GetSumOfSingleServices
    {
        get
        {

            var sums = (from dc in GetDashboardData                            
                        group dc by dc.serviceType into g
                        select g.Sum(sc => sc.serviceCost)).ToList();

            return sums;
        }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GetSumOfSingleServices");
        }

    }
```

I created a list of string by the following code below

```
public List<String> GetServiceNames
    {
        get
        {

            var names = (from dc in GetDashboardData
                         group dc by dc.serviceType into g                             
                         select g.First().serviceType).ToList();

            return names;
        }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GetServiceNames");
        }
    }
```

Now the data in these two lists are parallel meaning 
GetSumOfSingleServices[0] is the value for GetServiceNames[0] and so on.

I would like have a list that has the Strings ranked by the highest value from GetSumOfSingleServices first and so on.

So if the highest GetSumOfSingleServices[3] and its parallel string is  GetServiceNames[3], then I would like GetServiceNames[3] to be my first entry in the list.

Not sure how to sort through the list of strings by the double values.

That

Comment: Why don't you just create single list with a composite object containing both the name and the sum? It will be super easy to sort then. Synchronized indices smell really bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the general problem I'd use the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform#Comparison_to_other_languages), a common schema used in Perl. It should be easy to [port the underlying method to .net](http://jcheng.wordpress.com/2007/08/23/schwartzian-transform-in-c-30/)

Your case is even simpler as you have full control of the data access:

```
var tuples = from dc in GetDashboardData
            group dc by dc.serviceType into g
            select new{
                Cost = g.Sum(sc=>sc.serviceCost),
                Type = g.Key,
            };
var sorted = tuples.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Cost).Select(t=>t.Type);
return sorted.ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

With a source that looks like this, all your transformations become easy:

```
var compositeList = GetDashboardData
     .GroupBy(dc => dc.serviceType)
     .Select(g => new{
                    name = g.Key, 
                    sum = g.Sum(sc => sc.serviceCost)})
     .ToList();
```

(you might consider making a concrete class with two properties `name` and `sum` instead of the anonymous object declaration above).

Now:

```
compositeList.OrderByDescending(x => x.sum).Select(x => x.name);
```

and so on.

Synchronized lists suck.

Comment: Completely agree that synchronizing lists is a nightmare. If the data changes between GetSumOfSingleServices() and GetServiceNames(), or if the data comes back in an order you're not expecting, it's all over. This is a perfect way to get all the info you need in a consistent and predictable manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can either implement the `IComparable` interface to the class you are querying or create a new class that implements the `IComparer` interface and pass it as parameter to the sort method.